# I got this error : Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to show a loading screen, but I get this error:

```
E/flutter ( 3577): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter ( 3577): #0      FullScreenLoader.stopLoading (package:taba3ni/src/utils/popups/full_screen_loader.dart:36:36)
```

The error is when the `Get.overlayContext!` called.

Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:taba3ni/src/common_widgets/loaders/animation_loader.dart';

class FullScreenLoader {
  // open a full-screen loading with a given text and aniamtion
  // this method doesn't return anything

  static void openLoadingDialog(String text, String animation) {
    showDialog(
        context: Get.overlayContext!, 
        barrierDismissible:
            false, // the dialog can't be dismissed by tapping outside it
        builder: (_) => PopScope(
            canPop: false, // Disable popping with the back button
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              width: double.infinity,
              height: double.infinity,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(height: 250),
                  AnimationLoaderWidget(
                    'Please wait for a sec..',
                    animation: animation,
                    text: text,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )));
  }

  // Stop the currently open loading dialog

  static stopLoading() {
    if (Get.overlayContext != null) {
      Navigator.of(Get.overlayContext!).pop();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it's obvious that the expression Get.overlayContext! always returns null, avoid the use of exclamation operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GetX Dialog as mentioned below

```
class FullScreenLoader {
 // open a full-screen loading with a given text and aniamtion
 // this method doesn't return anything

 static void openLoadingDialog(String text, String animation) {
   Get.dialog(
       barrierDismissible: false, // the dialog can't be dismissed by tapping outside it
       PopScope(
           canPop: false, // Disable popping with the back button
           child: Container(
             color: Colors.white,
             width: double.infinity,
             height: double.infinity,
             child: Column(
               children: [
                 const SizedBox(height: 250),
                 AnimationLoaderWidget(
                   'Please wait for a sec..',
                   animation: animation,
                   text: text,
                 )
               ],
             ),
           )));
 }

 // Stop the currently open loading dialog

 static stopLoading() {
   if (Get.isDialogOpen) {
     Get.back();
   }
 }
}
```